# Generalized binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series

While doing an alternate way of establishing the binomial seris 
$$(1+x)^{\alpha}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\alpha \choose n}x^n=f(x) $$
where $\alpha$ is any number.
I am asked to prove the following: (assuming the converge of $f(x)$ for $|x|<1$)
show that $(1+x)f'(x)=\alpha f(x)$

My attempt is as follows:
$$\begin{align*} (1+x)f'(x) = & (1+x)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n{\alpha \choose n}x^{n-1}\\
= & \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[n{\alpha \choose n}+(n+1){\alpha \choose {n+1}}\right]x^n
\end{align*}$$
Now i wish to establish that 
$$ n{\alpha \choose n}+(n+1){\alpha \choose {n+1}}=\alpha{\alpha \choose n}$$
So I rewrite the lefthandside as 
$$\frac{n\alpha(\alpha-1)\dots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}+\frac{(n+1)\alpha(\alpha-1)\dots(\alpha-n+2)}{(n+1)!}=\frac{(n(\alpha-n+1)+1)\alpha(\alpha-1)\dots(\alpha-n+2)}{n!}$$ 
Here i have trouble continuing. If $\alpha$ where a whole number then I could have done the above by writing ${\alpha \choose n}=\frac{\alpha!}{n!(\alpha-n)!}$ but here it does not seem to apply. Any tips or hints?

Comment: I may be missing something.  What is $f(x)$?

Comment: @herbsteinberg My apologize its the right hand side of the binomal series , I will add it now.

Comment: That is what I thought.  $f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n}nx^{n-1}$.   You left out the $n$ multiplier.

Comment: @metamorphy I see , it is supposed to be $\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)...(\alpha-n)}{(n+1)!}$ correct?

Comment: @herbsteinberg I believe he just forgot to multiply by n in the first line, but it's then correct in the following line. The error is in the second term, the final term of the product being $(\alpha-n+2)$ instead of $(\alpha -n)$.

Comment: Yes correct Alexandros. I have changed it now as to make the post less confusing for future reads.

Comment: The key seems to be $(n+1)\binom{\alpha}{n+1}=(\alpha-n)\binom{\alpha}{n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{n\alpha(\alpha-1)\dots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}+\frac{(n+1)\alpha(\alpha-1)\dots(\alpha-n)}{(n+1)!}=\frac{(n)(\alpha)...(\alpha-n+1)+(\alpha)...(\alpha-n+1)(\alpha-n)}{n!}=\frac{(\alpha)...(\alpha-n+1)(n+(\alpha-n))}{n!}=\alpha\frac{(\alpha)...(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}=\alpha{\alpha \choose n}$